# Swift - Is checking whether a weak variable is nil or not thread-safe?

Tags: swift, queue, thread-safety, weak-references, abort

I have a process which runs for a long time and which I would like the ability to interrupt.

```
func longProcess (shouldAbort: @escaping ()->Bool) {

    // Runs a long loop and periodically checks shouldAbort(),
    // returning early if shouldAbort() returns true

}
```

Here's my class which uses it:

```
class Example {

    private var abortFlag: NSObject? = .init()

    private var dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue = .init(label: "Example")

    func startProcess () {
        let shouldAbort: ()->Bool = { [weak abortFlag] in
            return abortFlag == nil
        }

        dispatchQueue.async {
            longProcess(shouldAbort: shouldAbort)
        }
    }

    func abortProcess () {
        self.abortFlag = nil
    }
}
```

The `shouldAbort` closure captures a `weak` reference to `abortFlag`, and checks whether that reference points to `nil` or to an `NSObject`. Since the reference is `weak`, if the original `NSObject` is deallocated then the reference that is captured by the closure will suddenly be `nil` and the closure will start returning `true`. The closure will be called repeatedly during the `longProcess` function, which is occurring on the private `dispatchQueue`. The `abortProcess` method on the `Example` class will be externally called from some other queue. What if someone calls `abortProcess()`, thereby deallocating `abortFlag`, at the exact same time that `longProcess` is trying to perform the check to see if `abortFlag` has been deallocated yet? Is checking `myWeakReference == nil` a thread-safe operation?

Comment: Why are you using this dummy `NSObject` instance in the first place? It seems like the bool would work just the same.

Comment: Ignore my answer. It's factually correct (and interesting), but Rob's suggestion is better. Just don't do this.

Comment: I agree that Rob’s suggestion is the way to go, which is why I upvoted it, but my question was only partially fueled by need, the other part being curiosity. You directly answered my question, so your answer is the correct one. I’m happy though both to have read Rob’s answer and that it exists as part of this post for other people to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this bug ([Weak properties are not thread safe when reading SR-192](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-192)) indicating that weak reference reads weren't thread safe, but it has been fixed, which suggests that (absent any bugs in the runtime), weak reference reads are intended to be thread safe.

Also interesting: [Friday Q&A 2017-09-22: Swift 4 Weak References by Mike Ash](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2017-09-22-swift-4-weak-references.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can create the dispatched task as a `DispatchWorkItem`, which has a thread-safe [`isCancelled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem/1780829-iscancelled) property already. You can then dispatch that `DispatchWorkItem` to a queue and have it periodically check its `isCancelled`. You can then just [`cancel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem/1780910-cancel) the dispatched as such point you want to stop it.

---

Alternatively, when trying to wrap some work in an object, we’d often use `Operation`, instead, which encapsulates the task in its own class quite nicely:

```
class SomeLongOperation: Operation {
    override func main() {
        // Runs a long loop and periodically checks `isCancelled`

        while !isCancelled {
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1)
            print("tick")
        }
    }
}
```

And to create queue and add the operation to that queue:

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
let operation = SomeLongOperation()
queue.addOperation(operation)
```

And to cancel the operation:

```
operation.cancel()
```

Or

```
queue.cancelAllOperations()
```

---

Bottom line, whether you use `Operation` (which is, frankly, the “go-to” solution for wrapping some task in its own object) or roll-your-own with `DispatchWorkItem`, the idea is the same, namely that you don’t need to have your own state property to detect cancellation of the task. Both dispatch queues and operation queues already have nice mechanisms to simplify this process for you.